# How to display the date a directory folder on ftp was modified

Tags: media-library, ftp

We have our site running on wordpress, but we upload all of our PDF files via FTP and NOT the WP media.

I want to be able to display in a WP Page, the last time a file, or a "folder in the FTP directory" was modified.

I have tried using the different Wordpress Loops for last modified, but this will not solve my problem, as this only displays the last time the post/page was modified, but, becuase the documents displayed in pages are not being uplaoded via the WP Page editor, nor the WP Media Library, they are essentially not being "updated/modified" according wordpress.

```
$getLastModDir = filemtime("../../path/to/directory/.");
echo "$getLastModDir was last modified" . date ("F d Y");
```

or

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
$fmtime = filemtime($filename);
if (!$fmtime) {
    echo "$filename was last modified:: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", $fmtime);
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Meaning, is there a way to find a file in the ftp, from inside a wordpress page, and see the last time it was edited?

Please Help!

Thanks :)

Comment: You have the right idea. Where are the files located?

Comment: This information will not be available in WP, or through a WP function, or in WP's database. But the following php function you have filemtime() should work. Just make sure $filename has the correct path_to_file/file_name.pdf